# How get array instead of object after db select in laravel

Tags: select, laravel, eloquent

I have this query

```
DB::table('my_table')->whereIn('column_id', $tagList)->get(array('product_id'));
```

But in result I got array of stdClass objects

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[964]
      public 'product_id' => int 19
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[961]
      public 'product_id' => int 20
```

Is any possibility to get value as simple array ?

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 19
  1 => 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `lists`

```
DB::table('my_table')->whereIn('column_id', $tagList)->lists('child_id');
```